# Azure AD B2C: AcquireTokenSilentAsync returns empty access token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I followed the steps in [Create an ASP.NET web app with Azure Active Directory B2C sign-up, sign-in, profile edit, and password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi) and used the sample code to prototype Azure AD B2C for our company.

- The only change is that I used my domain name instead of the sample domain and modified the web.config
- I have defined the scope and App ID for API application
- I get the Id token but **not** the access token

Any suggestion on what the issue could be?

[image]

Comment: App Id for the API app is https://*****.onmicrosoft.com/tasks/ . Scope names are "read" and "write"

Comment: In the portal there is a warning "No subscription is linked to this B2C tenant...". Does this have anything to do with no access token being returned?

Answer (score 2):

One of the steps is missing in [Create an ASP.NET web app with Azure Active Directory B2C sign-up, sign-in, profile edit, and password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi) documentation.

The access token is returned once you give the API access to Web Application following [the steps described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#publishing-permissions).

Comment: @spottedmahn why are you linking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi all over the place in your suggested edits?

Comment: Hello @jontro - don't you find it easier to read titles than urls?  And more self-documenting...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when everything about my request was correct *except the scope I was requesting.*  I would get an id_token returned, but not an access_token.  I was using the sample from here: https://dzimchuk.net/setting-up-your-asp-net-core-2-0-apps-and-services-for-azure-ad-b2c/ (a *superb* article by the way). I had run the app but without having defined the read_values scope in the Application Published Scopes in my Azure B2C tenant. The issue you describe manifested itself in these lines of code from that sample.

```
var result = await client.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.TokenEndpointRequest.Code, new[] { $"{authOptions.ApiIdentifier}/read_values" });

context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
```

> **result.IdToken was fine, result.AccessToken was null until I correctly defined the read_values scope in my azure b2c tenant.**